# Issue with uri while loading data in database

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

Can I use both command `-generate_uri` and `-uri_id` {any one element name} while inserting data into database through MLCP for getting unique uri? Or can I use multiple element name (-uri_id {first element name}, {second element name}) in MLCP command. Please any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with command-line options, but you can manipulate the document uri with a transform. The MLCP guide provides an example transform doing just that. For details see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_17589

HTH!